# How can I use "Suggesting" in Google Slides?

Tags: google-slides

Google Docs has the following **Suggesting** function. How can I use the same function in Google Slides?

**Screenshot:**

[image: Suggesting in Google Docs]

Answer (score 12):

According to a Google Docs community specialist, [the *Suggesting* feature is only available on Google Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm02RJ9edydzzk/?hl=en&gpf=%23!msg%2Fdocs%2F2RJ9edydzzk%2FP8wG_JuqNAAJ&msgid=P8wG_JuqNAAJ).

Comment: Welcome :) I didn't downvote this answer and I haven't idea about why it was downvoted as there isn't much to say besides that the quoted thread is from 2016.